# AWS CLI commands won't run

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've installed the AWS Command Line Interface using pip by following Amazon's instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html).  I also downloaded my access key id and secret access key into ~/aws/rootkey.csv.  However, after the installation, the aws command doesn't work.  If I try to simply verify the installation with the command "aws help", I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname configure: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I get the same error if I try to run "aws configure".

Since I have my identity (.pem) file in a non-standard location, ~/aws/ec2-t1-micro.pem, I tried specifying it on the command line "aws -i /Users/me/aws/ec2-t1-micro.pem help" but I still get the same error.

Just in case aws can't find my .pem file, I also created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s ~/aws ~/.aws
```

This didn't help either.

If I run the command verbosely with "aws -v help" I see:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname help: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Finally, I downloaded the awscli source from Github and searched for the error message but I couldn't find anything.  I also searched the source for the string "ssh" to see if the error was being generated by a call to ssh but I couldn't find anything.  This installation is *supposed* to be easy.  I've searched the Internet and I see where this error arises in other situations but nothing particular to running the aws command.

By the way, I did create an inbound security group rule for ssh and have no problems accessing my server using the command: "ssh -i [path_to_my_id_file] ubuntu@[my_public_dns_name]".

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: I doubt if your 'aws' command is really the awscli or it just run SSH. Could you run `which aws; ls -lad $( which aws )` and update the question with that command's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a long time ago, I created an alias for ssh called "aws" since I was using my instance so frequently.  My bad.